# QPluginLoader moved to thread

Tags: qt, qthread

I'm building an application that will rely heavily on plugins: the core gets data from a serial interface and delivers it to each plugin so each one can decide what to do with it.

My design allows the plugins to build a Widget that is attached to a MDIArea through a QMdiSubWindow.
This worked until I needed mutexes, as everything was running in the same thread I got deadlocks very fast.
So I though that moving each plugin to a different thread could solve this. The problem is that (for now), the QMdiSubWindow are not being created anymore and I have no clue why this is happening.

The core communicates with plugins by using signals and slots.

This is how I load my plugins and move them into a thread:

```
QPluginLoader loader( the_path );
QObject* plugin = loader.instance();
if( plugin!=0 )
{
    //Connect install subwindows request
    connect( plugin, SIGNAL(install_plugin_window(QString,QWidget*)), this, SLOT(onRequestInstallSubwindow(QString,QWidget*)) );

    QThread* consumer = new QThread;
    plugin->moveToThread( consumer );
    consumer->start();

    PluginInterface* pl = qobject_cast<PluginInterface*>(plugin);
    pl->registerSubWindow();
}
```

Please note that this is a simplification of the original code.
I followed this approach (moving my plugin to a thread) basing on this article http://www.christeck.de/wp/2010/10/23/the-great-qthread-mess/

registerSubWindow() is the method in my plugin that creates the widget:

```
void PluginDrier::registerSubWindow()
{
    widget = new Form();
    emit install_plugin_window( "Plugin Widget", widget );
}
```

Which emits a signal that is catched by the core with this slot, which registers the generated widget as the mentioned MdiSubWindow:

```
void MainWindow::onRequestInstallSubwindow( QString title, QWidget* content )
{
    QMdiSubWindow* subwindow = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow( content );
    subwindow->setWindowTitle( title );
    subwindow->setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint |     Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt widgets working only in the GUI thread. You may try to move plugin inner operations to different threads, but all GUI must remain in your main thread.

Try this:

```
void PluginDrier::registerSubWindow()
{
    widget = new Form();
    widget->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread ());
    emit install_plugin_window( "Plugin Widget", widget );
}
```

but i haven't test it, may not work. Also, keep in mind that all communications between your inner logic and the gui should be thread-safe if my solution would work.

Comment: Could I move the widget to GUI thread in onRequestInstallSubwindow() better?

Comment: The question is: given that the widgets have to be in the main thread, what is the value in creating them in separate threads?  It seems to me it would be better to move your data reading into a different thread, and keep all your GUI operations in the main one.

Comment: How could I separate my plugins then into two pieces? Maybe include a Worker Object inside my plugin, that would contain all inner logic and transfer that Worker object to the new thread?

Comment: @clinisbut >Could I move the widget to GUI thread in onRequestInstallSubwindow() better? - No you cant, that operation must be done in thread where you create your object.

Comment: @clinisbut yes. idea with worker object is good, you may do this.